# Problems with multiple proximity alerts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alert, android-pendingintent, proximity

I've found some threads related with multiple proximity alerts, but none of them solve my problem =(

I've a class that creates multiple proximity alerts (this is the important code):

```
public void activateAlerts(){
    Database db = new Database(activity.getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = db.getPois();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    int latitudeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude");
    int longitudeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude");

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        double latitude = cursor.getDouble(latitudeIndex);
        double longitude = cursor.getDouble(longitudeIndex);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("latitude",latitude);
        bundle.putDouble("longitude",longitude);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        Random generator = new Random();
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), generator.nextInt(), intent, 0);

        getActivity().registerReceiver(new AlertIntentReceiver(), filter);
        locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, 2500, -1, pi);
    }
    Log.i("ALERT", "ALERT");
}
```

And this is the receiver, that shows a notification:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    double latitude = b.getDouble("latitude");
    double longitude = b.getDouble("longitude");

    Log.i("ALERT", latitude+","+longitude);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Intent intentPi = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intentPi,0);

    Notification mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_directions_grey_24dp,"Map",pintent)
                    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,mBuilder);
}
```

The problem is that I'm receiving too many "BroadcastReceivers" with same point for the latitude and longitude. For example, this is the last Logcat information:

> 39.495412,-0.354705
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> 39.4605203,-0.3478213
>
> ... [same values]

What is the problem? How can I receive only different latitude and longitude?

Comment: "Cursor cursor = db.getPois();" How are you actually getting the positions?

Comment: db.getPois() returns a Cursor with the pois information (latitude and longitude are included in that cursor).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have need to have a continued location update using Request Location Updates or Location Listener:

Comment: I think that it is not important with my problem, no? =/ What you are saying helps to the user to show notifications on the correct moment, but I'm receiving repeated values on the BroadcastReceiver